# OPL Cplex Optimization

Tags: cplex

The conditional constraint is working to find out `M`,

```
{(U[k][i][j] == 1)   &&   ( A[k][i] >= (-1 + (D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5))  
=> M[k][i][j] == 1;  }
```

This expression is working to find out decision variable `M` if both the conditions are satisfied, I have to find out decisions on the following other conditions also,

```
if {(V[k][i][j] == 1) && ( A[k][i] < ((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5))  
O[k][i][j] == 1;  }  
if {(V[k][i][j] == 1) && ( A[k][i] < ((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5))  
Z[k][i][j] == 1;  }
```

How can I write expressions for the above to find out decision variables, `O`, `Z`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: If U be 1 and A be lesser than D*S*52*5, the decision variable M is 1,         If V be 1 and A be greater than D*S*52*5, then other alternatives O and Z will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
((V[k][i][j] == 1) && ( A[k][i] <= -1+((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5))) 
=>  (O[k][i][j] == 1);   

 ((V[k][i][j] == 1) && ( A[k][i] <= -1+((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5))) 
 => (Z[k][i][j] == 1);
```

Comment: Hi,Using these three  codes for M, O, Z with given two input values (one is M=1, second is O, Z = 1), but in run, iam getting solns. as M=1, O=1, Z=1 for the two input values.

Comment: Expecting either M or O and Z will be 1, but solns. will be M=1, O=1, Z=1